# OpenCV `sortIdx` returning unexpected results

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv

I try to use OpenCV `sortIdx` (in C++ / Objective C) but get unexpected results:

```
Mat test = (Mat_<double>(1, 6) << 15.342105,5.000000,27.000000,1.1,2.1,3.1);
std::cout << test << "\n";
Mat testIdx;
sortIdx(test, testIdx, CV_SORT_ASCENDING | CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW);
std::cout << testIdx << "\n";
```

This gives output:

```
[15.342105, 5, 27, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 2]
```

While I would expect

```
[15.342105, 5, 27, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1]
[4, 3, 5, 0, 1, 2]
```

I have no clue why, the normal `sort` function returns correctly the sorted sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorted sequence is

```
{test[3], test[4], test[5], test[1], test[0], test[2]}
```

which corresponds reasonably well with your result.

You're expecting the result to be a mapping from input to output ("where would this item in the input go?"), but it's actually a mapping from output to input ("where would this item in the output come from?").